# Count calc with 0 values on second column

Tags: mysql

I need some help. 
I have to show 0 values on the count distinct rif_user, the second column:

user table

idu                             date_of_birth

11111                           01/01/2000

22222                           02/02/1999

booking table

rif_use                         booking_date

11111                           01/01/2000

22222                           02/02/1999

I tried with this query but it doesn't work. Why?

```
SELECT
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, u.date_of_birth, CURDATE()) as age
   , COUNT(DISTINCT(p.rif_user)) as count
FROM `booked` as p
LEFT JOIN users as u ON p.rif_user=u.idu 
WHERE p.booking_date < '2017-11-24'
GROUP BY age
```

I would like these results:

age                 count

18                  **0**

19                  20

20                  5

etc                 etc

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add the tables with example data.. Where not here to reverse engineer your SQL.

Comment: added two tables

Comment: Please provide sample data, as well as sample output of what is currently occurring as well as what your desired result is.

Comment: ok i think done now

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem? You still have not yet provided what the current "doesn't work" state is. Also, your sample data make no sense and the tables look identical and neither has any relation to the output you provided.